# Draw Connector Lines between Divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a Tournament bracket and I am following an example however it is missing the lines and I would like to add them

https://codepen.io/jbeason/pen/Wbaedb

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Holtwood+One+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web|Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>March Madness Stock Matchup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="hero">
    <div class="hero-wrap">
     <p class="intro" id="intro">flexbox</p>
         <h1 id="headline">Tournament</h1>
         <p class="year"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> 2015 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></p>
     <p>Ballin' Outta Control</p>
   </div>
    </header>


    <section id="bracket">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="split split-one">
        <div class="round round-one current">
            <div class="round-details">Round 1<br/><span class="date">March 16</span></div>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Duke<span class="score">76</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Virginia<span class="score">82</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Wake Forest<span class="score">64</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Clemson<span class="score">56</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">North Carolina<span class="score">68</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Florida State<span class="score">54</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">NC State<span class="score">74</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Maryland<span class="score">92</span></li>
            </ul>           
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Georgia Tech<span class="score">78</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Georgia<span class="score">80</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Auburn<span class="score">64</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Florida<span class="score">63</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Kentucky<span class="score">70</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Alabama<span class="score">59</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Vanderbilt<span class="score">64</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Gonzaga<span class="score">68</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND ONE -->

        <div class="round round-two">
            <div class="round-details">Round 2<br/><span class="date">March 18</span></div>         
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND TWO -->

        <div class="round round-three">
            <div class="round-details">Round 3<br/><span class="date">March 22</span></div>         
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND THREE -->        
    </div> 

<div class="champion">
        <div class="semis-l">
            <div class="round-details">west semifinals <br/><span class="date">March 26-28</span></div>     
            <ul class ="matchup championship">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="final">
            <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
            <div class="round-details">championship <br/><span class="date">March 30 - Apr. 1</span></div>      
            <ul class ="matchup championship">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="semis-r">       
            <div class="round-details">east semifinals <br/><span class="date">March 26-28</span></div>     
            <ul class ="matchup championship">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>


    <div class="split split-two">


        <div class="round round-three">
            <div class="round-details">Round 3<br/><span class="date">March 22</span></div>                     
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND THREE -->    

        <div class="round round-two">
            <div class="round-details">Round 2<br/><span class="date">March 18</span></div>                     
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND TWO -->
        <div class="round round-one current">
            <div class="round-details">Round 1<br/><span class="date">March 16</span></div>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Minnesota<span class="score">62</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Northwestern<span class="score">54</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Michigan<span class="score">68</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Iowa<span class="score">66</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Illinois<span class="score">64</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Wisconsin<span class="score">56</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Purdue<span class="score">36</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Boise State<span class="score">40</span></li>
            </ul>           
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Penn State<span class="score">38</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Indiana<span class="score">44</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Ohio State<span class="score">52</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">VCU<span class="score">80</span></li>
            </ul>   
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">USC<span class="score">58</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Cal<span class="score">59</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="matchup">
                <li class="team team-top">Virginia Tech<span class="score">74</span></li>
                <li class="team team-bottom">Dartmouth<span class="score">111</span></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>  <!-- END ROUND ONE -->                          
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="share">
            <div class="share-wrap">
                <a class="share-icon" href="https://twitter.com/_joebeason"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a class="share-icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a class="share-icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
            </div>
    </section>

body {
  font-family: "Istok Web", sans-serif;
  background: url("http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/HNCK2189-1300x866.jpg")
    no-repeat #000;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.hero {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fcfcfc;
}
.hero h1 {
  font-family: "Holtwood One SC", serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 5.4em;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
.hero p {
  font-family: "Abel", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #5cca87;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.hero-wrap {
  padding: 3.5em 10px;
}
.hero p.intro {
  font-family: "Holtwood One SC", serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
.hero p.year {
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  font-size: 34px;
  margin: -25px 0 25px;
}
.hero p.year i {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#bracket {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.9);
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.split {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 42%;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.champion {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 16%;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 230px 0\9;
}
.champion i {
  color: #a0a6a8;
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.round {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 95%;
  width: 30.8333%\9;
}
.split-two {
}
.split-one .round {
  margin: 0 2.5% 0 0;
}
.split-two .round {
  margin: 0 0 0 2.5%;
}
.matchup {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.score {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: right;
  color: #2c7399;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}
.team {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.round-two .matchup {
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.round-three .matchup {
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 130px 0;
}
.round-details {
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #2c7399;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}
.champion li,
.round li {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 0.45;
}
.current li {
  opacity: 1;
}
.current li.team {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.vote-options {
  display: block;
  height: 52px;
}
.share .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.share-icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
}
.share-wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
.final {
  margin: 4.5em 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.share-icon {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.35;
}
.share-icon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.5s;
  animation: pulse 0.5s;
}
.date {
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Istok Web", sans-serif;
  color: #3f915f;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0 1%;
  }
  .champion {
    width: 14%;
  }
  .split {
    width: 43%;
  }
  .split-one .vote-box {
    margin-left: 138px;
  }
  .hero p.intro {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .hero p.year {
    margin: 5px 0 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .split,
  .champion {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 35px 5%;
  }
  .champion {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
  .split {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .hero p.intro {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .hero h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  .hero p {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .split {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 25px 2.5%;
  }
  .round {
    width: 21%;
  }
  .current {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .hero h1 {
    font-size: 2.15em;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .hero p.intro {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
  }
  .round-details {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  .hero-wrap {
    padding: 2.5em;
  }
  .hero p.year {
    margin: 5px 0 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

[image]

I would like to do something like above(of course a straight line).

I am not sure how to go about it, first I thought of wrapping those 4 slots into another div and put a border but this won't work as the wrapper will be bigger and the border will be too big.

I then thought doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AcuPp/3/

where I have another container of "connectors" and "lines" but this seems like it will be finiky with the margins.

Comment: Another idea you could try is grabbing the right X value of your left sided divs (left brackets) and the left X value of your right sided divs (right brackets) and create a simple line that goes inbetween both of those values and extends from the top Y value to the bottom Y value of the left sided divs. You could just make a simple line in the middle of your Y coordinates that extends out to your right sided divs. You could simple just use a div for the line, set the height to as mentioned, and the width to however thick you want it to be. You'd have to use JS and possibly z-indexing + abs pos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with pseudo element.

Relevant code:

```
.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% + 5px);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    width:4px;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-top:2px solid red;
}
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
    right:calc(100% + 5px);
    left:auto;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-left:0;
}

.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after{
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0%;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
    border-top:0;
}
.matchup {
    position: relative;
}
```

Full code

```css
body {font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;background: url("http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/HNCK2189-1300x866.jpg") no-repeat #000;background-size: cover;min-height: 100%;margin: 0;}
.hero {position:relative; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; color: #fcfcfc; }
.hero h1 {font-family: 'Holtwood One SC', serif;font-weight: normal;font-size: 5.4em;margin:0 0 20px; text-shadow:0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing:-1px;}
.hero p {font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase; color: #5CCA87; letter-spacing: 6px;text-shadow:0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);font-size: 1.2em;}
.hero-wrap {padding: 3.5em 10px;}
.hero p.intro {font-family: 'Holtwood One SC', serif;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 1px;font-size: 3em;margin-bottom:-40px;}
.hero p.year {color: #fff; letter-spacing: 20px; font-size: 34px; margin: -25px 0 25px;}
.hero p.year i {font-size: 14px;vertical-align: middle;}
#bracket {overflow:hidden;background-color: #e1e1e1;background-color:rgba(225,225,225,0.9);padding-top: 20px;font-size: 12px;padding: 40px 0;}
.container {max-width: 1100px;margin: 0 auto;display:block;display: -webkit-box;display: -moz-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display: -webkit-flex;display: flex;-webkit-flex-direction:row;flex-direction: row;}
.split {display:block;float:left;display: -webkit-box;display: -moz-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display:flex;width: 42%;-webkit-flex-direction:row;-moz-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;}
.champion {float:left;display:block;width: 16%;-webkit-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-webkit-align-self:center;align-self:center;margin-top: -15px;text-align: center;padding: 230px 0\9;} 
.champion i {color: #a0a6a8; font-size: 45px;padding: 10px 0; }
.round {display:block;float:left;display: -webkit-box;display: -moz-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: -webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;width:95%;width:30.8333%\9;}
.split-two {}
.split-one .round {margin: 0 2.5% 0 0;}
.split-two .round {margin: 0 0 0 2.5%;}
.matchup {margin:0;width: 100%;padding: 10px 0;height:60px;-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;transition: all 0.2s;}
.score {font-size: 11px;text-transform: uppercase;float: right;color: #2C7399;font-weight: bold;font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;position: absolute;right: 5px;}
.team {padding: 0 5px;margin: 3px 0;height: 25px; line-height: 25px;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;position: relative;}
.round-two .matchup {margin:0; height: 60px;padding: 50px 0;}
.round-three .matchup {margin:0; height: 60px; padding: 130px 0;}
.round-details {font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #2C7399;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;height: 40px;}
.champion li, .round li {background-color: #fff;box-shadow: none; opacity: 0.45;}
.current li {opacity: 1;}
.current li.team {background-color: #fff;box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);opacity: 1;}
.vote-options {display: block;height: 52px;}
.share .container {margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}
.share-icon {font-size: 24px; color: #fff;padding: 25px;}
.share-wrap {max-width: 1100px; text-align: center; margin: 60px auto;}
.final {margin: 4.5em 0;}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.share-icon {color: #fff; opacity: 0.35; }
.share-icon:hover { opacity:1;  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.5s; animation: pulse 0.5s;}
.date {font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 2px;font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;color:#3F915F;}



@media screen and (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1099px) {
  .container {margin: 0 1%;}
  .champion {width: 14%;}
  .split {width:43%; }
  .split-one .vote-box {margin-left: 138px;}
  .hero p.intro {font-size: 28px;}
  .hero p.year {margin: 5px 0 10px;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {-webkit-flex-direction:column;-moz-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;}
  .split, .champion {width: 90%;margin: 35px 5%;}
  .champion {-webkit-box-ordinal-group:3;-moz-box-ordinal-group:3;-ms-flex-order:3;-webkit-order:3;order:3;}
  .split {border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6; padding-bottom: 20px;}
  .hero p.intro {font-size: 24px;}
  .hero h1 {font-size: 3em; margin: 15px 0;}
  .hero p {font-size: 1em;}
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

  .split {width: 95%;margin: 25px 2.5%;}
  .round {width:21%;}
  .current {-webkit-flex-grow:1;-moz-flex-grow:1;flex-grow:1;}
  .hero h1 {font-size: 2.15em; letter-spacing: 0;margin:0; }
  .hero p.intro {font-size: 1.15em;margin-bottom: -10px;}
  .round-details {font-size: 90%;}
  .hero-wrap {padding: 2.5em;}
  .hero p.year {margin: 5px 0 10px; font-size: 18px;}

}

.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% + 5px);
    top: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    width:4px;
    border-top:2px solid red;
    bottom: 50%;
}
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
    right:calc(100% + 5px);
    left:auto;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-left:0;
}

.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after{
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0%;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
    border-top:0;
}
.matchup {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Holtwood+One+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script|Herr+Von+Muellerhoff' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web|Roboto+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <title>March Madness Stock Matchup</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="hero">
    <div class="hero-wrap">
     <p class="intro" id="intro">flexbox</p>
   <h1 id="headline">Tournament</h1>
   <p class="year"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> 2015 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></p>
     <p>Ballin' Outta Control</p>
   </div>
 </header>


 <section id="bracket">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="split split-one">
  <div class="round round-one current">
   <div class="round-details">Round 1<br/><span class="date">March 16</span></div>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Duke<span class="score">76</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Virginia<span class="score">82</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Wake Forest<span class="score">64</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Clemson<span class="score">56</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">North Carolina<span class="score">68</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Florida State<span class="score">54</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">NC State<span class="score">74</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Maryland<span class="score">92</span></li>
   </ul>   
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Georgia Tech<span class="score">78</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Georgia<span class="score">80</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Auburn<span class="score">64</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Florida<span class="score">63</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Kentucky<span class="score">70</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Alabama<span class="score">59</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Vanderbilt<span class="score">64</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Gonzaga<span class="score">68</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND ONE -->

  <div class="round round-two">
   <div class="round-details">Round 2<br/><span class="date">March 18</span></div>   
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND TWO -->
  
  <div class="round round-three">
   <div class="round-details">Round 3<br/><span class="date">March 22</span></div>   
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND THREE -->  
 </div> 

<div class="champion">
  <div class="semis-l">
   <div class="round-details">west semifinals <br/><span class="date">March 26-28</span></div>  
   <ul class ="matchup championship">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="final">
   <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
   <div class="round-details">championship <br/><span class="date">March 30 - Apr. 1</span></div>  
   <ul class ="matchup championship">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="semis-r">  
   <div class="round-details">east semifinals <br/><span class="date">March 26-28</span></div>  
   <ul class ="matchup championship">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="vote-count">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
 </div>


 <div class="split split-two">


  <div class="round round-three">
   <div class="round-details">Round 3<br/><span class="date">March 22</span></div>      
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND THREE --> 

  <div class="round round-two">
   <div class="round-details">Round 2<br/><span class="date">March 18</span></div>      
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">&nbsp;<span class="score">&nbsp;</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND TWO -->
   <div class="round round-one current">
   <div class="round-details">Round 1<br/><span class="date">March 16</span></div>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Minnesota<span class="score">62</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Northwestern<span class="score">54</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Michigan<span class="score">68</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Iowa<span class="score">66</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Illinois<span class="score">64</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Wisconsin<span class="score">56</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Purdue<span class="score">36</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Boise State<span class="score">40</span></li>
   </ul>   
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Penn State<span class="score">38</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Indiana<span class="score">44</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Ohio State<span class="score">52</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">VCU<span class="score">80</span></li>
   </ul> 
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">USC<span class="score">58</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Cal<span class="score">59</span></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">Virginia Tech<span class="score">74</span></li>
    <li class="team team-bottom">Dartmouth<span class="score">111</span></li>
   </ul>          
  </div> <!-- END ROUND ONE -->              
 </div>
 </div>
 </section>
 <section class="share">
   <div class="share-wrap">
    <a class="share-icon" href="https://twitter.com/_joebeason"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="share-icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a class="share-icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
   </div>
 </section>
```

If you want a full connection you can adjust like below:

```css
.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  bottom: 50%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) bottom left /50% 2px, 
    linear-gradient(red, red) center      /2px 100%, 
    linear-gradient(red, red) top right   /50% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(odd)::after,
.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.split-one ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.split-two ul.matchup:nth-child(even)::after {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0%;
  transform: scale(-1);
}

.matchup {
  position: relative;
}
```

Full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/fohbctsj/1/

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it out, got a few questions though, I never seen the use of slash before like that like /50% what does it do. Second the thick small line what controls the position of that. In my code as I made some changes it is off a bit.

Comment: the `/` is the separtion between the size and the position so it's on `bottom left` with a size `50% 2px` (width height) ... The thick small line is the addition of two small line from each pseudo element. If you look closely you will notice the same shape that I simply scale to have its mirror for the other pseudo element. The connector is actually the combination of two shapes.

Comment: @chobo2 check this : https://jsfiddle.net/fohbctsj/2/ I have update the coloration so you can better see the trick

Comment: Sorry, I am not seeing what you want me to look up at. I am also confused why you need to use the odd/even for your selectors.

Comment: @chobo2 look how the connector is having two colors (green and red) ... The trick is to alternate the styles, the even selector will create the green part and the odd selector will create the red part. Try to remove the code for all the odd for example and you will see what the even selector will give you. Do the same by removing the even and keeping the odd.

Comment: Ok, I see it now what you mean (I don't see where you changed one to red and the other to green though)

Comment: @chobo2 I appied a filter to transform the red to green: https://jsfiddle.net/fohbctsj/2/

Comment: Ah,now I see. Still trying to understand it all. The lines on mine are a bit off on my version (it seems to happen on round 3 in your version the notch does not line up )